# Add "--Select--" in ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a Combobox the data for which is being populating from Sharepoint List.
I need to add a value called "--Select--" in the combobox and set it as default upon launching the application.

I cannot add "--Select" in the Sharepoint list.  Please assist on how can i do it.

Below is the code.

```
teamName = templatedata.getTeamName();
cmbteams.DataSource = teamName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this:

```
cmbteams.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
```

or

```
cmbteams.Items.Add(new Item("Select", 0));
```

you can set default like this:

```
cmbteams.SelectedValue=0;
```

or

```
cmbteams.SelectedIndex=0;
```

Comment: any reason for downvoting??

Answer (score 1):

I assume Winform,

```
    cmbteams.Items.Insert(0, "SELECT");
    cmbteams.SelectedIndex = 0;
```